# strange error messages in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a web project. I just opened up a solution and tried to run it (offline) in a browser, but suddenly something seems to have happened because it won't run.

An error page is shown with the following error message:

*"Unrecognized attribute 'targetFrameworkMoniker'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive."*

It refers to the following line in web.config

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFrameworkMoniker=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">
```

In the error list in VS there is a lots of errors (about 60 lines), for example:
"Could not find schema information for the element 'compilers"

What can have happened? I recently renamed the projects folder but that is the only thing I can think of, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to this and see if that fixes it:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

I haven't come across targetFrameworkMoniker before and the [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx) for the compilation element doesn't have a targetFrameworkMokiker attribute listed.